# How to calcuate (n) no of coming saturdays with Laravel and Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

How can i get the coming (n) Saturdays form a specific date.

Like if i want to calculate 6 Saturdays from now these will be like so.

- 2017-04-01
- 2017-04-08
- 2017-04-15
- 2017-04-22
- 2017-04-29
- 2017-05-06

What i have tried so for is

```
$dateDay = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$year = $dateDay->year;
$month = $dateDay->month;
$days = $dateDay->daysInMonth;
$saturdays=[];
foreach (range(1, $days) as $day) {
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day);
    if ($date->isSaturday()===true) {
        $saturdays[]=($date->day);
    }
}
print_r($saturdays);
```

but this only shows Saturdays of the current month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). This will return a Carbon object with `2017-05-06` date:

```
Carbon::parse('first saturday')->addWeeks(5);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,but i need all the list of dates,not just 2017-05-06

Comment: Why not execute the above in a loop and push that in your array with respect to the weeks

Comment: Oh,you are right,i can change days with loop as well.